# How to deserialize attribute named “value” with RestSharp without breaking the code style?

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to deserialize a XML file where some of the nodes are like this:

```
<clouds value="68" name="broken clouds"/>
```

The elementes with an attribute called 'value' will not deserialize.

My class:

```
public class CloudsData
{        
    public string value { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 

}
```

Renaming "Value" to "value" helps, but breaking the Code Style.
Are there other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to decorate your property with [XmlAttribute], like value with [XmlAttribute("value")]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark your property with [`SerializeAsAttribute`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/SerializeAsAttribute.cs):

```
public class CloudsData
{        
    [SerializeAs(Name = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I think he wants the opposite, he said  I am using RestSharp to deserialize a XML file where some of the nodes are like this:, not serialize as

Comment: Attribute name is a little bad, but I think it's used for both serialization and deserialization :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Based on my testing, it looks like you need DeserializeAsAttribute in this particular case.  https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Deserializers/DeserializeAsAttribute.cs